# Shortcut to get out of parenthesis in IntelliJ (or possibly other IDE as well)

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Let's say `|` is a cursor pointer. What I want to do is to get out from parenthesis once I finish typing paremeters. In step by step explanation:

```
// 1: type function name
void function|

// 2: openening paren automatically generate closing paren for convenience
void function(|)

// 3: type paremeters...
void function(42|)

// 4: ...and get out of parenthesis!
void function(42)|
```

Usually I use right arrow to do that, but using arrows are not so convenient, and I wonder if there's any shortcut for this. What I'm curious at is IntelliJ's, but it would be very nice if you can tell me shortcut of any other Jetbrain IDE or Visual Studio, etc.

Comment: You know that's not actually valid in any language, right?

Comment: Oh I didnt relized that until now, but since it isn't the point of the question, let me just keep it unedited☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut you're looking for, on most keyboards, is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> -- this won't work on the keypad, only the main numbers at the top of the keyboard. Technically this isn't a shortcut, you're actually typing the close parenthesis, but IntelliJ is smart enough not to double up on them so it's as good as a shortcut in this case.

Comment: Shift + zero? that just inputs a zero on my azerty keyboard... is that supposed to input a closing parent ? PS: The other solution works perfectly, and works for all keyboards layouts

Comment: That'll be why it has a higher score then... BTW: I did say 'most' keyboards. France and Belgium should just use standard English keyboards like the Canadians ;)  For Azerty it's the key to the right of the 0 (usually).

Comment: Yeah, I added a comment for other stupid people like me, because i spent 3 whole minutes figuring why it didn't work :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (on Windows). The Action name is **`Complete Current Statement`**

On Mac if you want to know the shortcut invoke <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Find Action) then type **`Complete Current Statement`** it will show you the *shortcut* for the action as well

[image]

Comment: I'm glad to find out exact term (complete current statement) amd a shortcut for that, and I really thanks to you for giving me the exact answer for my question. But it seems that Dollery's answer is the one I'm going to use for now on, so after some consideration I decided to choice his answer, sorry.

Comment: Dear random non-english reader, this is the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another setting that I find convenient to use is this option.

`Settings - Smart Keys - Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab`